# Using StreamWriter and FileSystemWatcher Together

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, filesystemwatcher, streamwriter

I have a program that is monitoring a directory for changes using the `FileSystemWatcher` class. I have some other clients writing to this directory using a `StreamWriter`. "Sometimes", in the filesystemwatcher created event, when I try to access the file, I get an error.

This is very hard to debug as it does not happen frequently. The client is closing the stream properly by enclosing it in a `Using` block. The error is on the lines of "This application cannot use the file as it is being used by another process". I don't quite understand this, when the client is using the same code to write files to directory why does the error show up only sporadically. Sometimes, manual copy throws an error while most times it goes through.

The directory in question is not a network directory, its local. Please suggest.

Client Code

```
using (StreamWriter ss = new StreamWriter(input)) {
    ss.WriteLine(args(0));
    ss.Close();
}
```

Monitoring Application Event Code

```
public void Temp()
{
FileSystemWatcher fs = new FileSystemWatcher();

fs.Path = GlobalStatics.PathWorkOrders;
fs.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
fs.Filter = "*.wo";
fs.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

fs.Created += CreatedEvent;
}

public void CreatedEvent(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        string guidStr = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(e.FullPath);

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(e.FullPath))
        {
            //Processing
            sr.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you show the code that you are using perhaps you need to create an instance of the StreamWriter if this is being done in a for loop but can't tell without seeing your code..

Comment: This is inevitable.  You'll have a wait for a while and try again.

Comment: try using Thread.sleep(1000) before the StreamReader object creation!

Answer (score 3):

It's kind of hard without the code, but I guess you're seeing a race condition. This is what I believe is happening most of the times.

- Process A is updating a file with the StreamWriter, locking the file.
- Process A is done updating and closes the file.
- The FileSystemWatcher wakes up and processes the file.

  Sometimes, due to timing issues you can't control, the order is a little different:
- Process A is updating a file with the StreamWriter, locking the file.
- The FileSystemWatcher wakes up and processes the file.
- Process A is done updating and closes the file.

  Because the file is locked, your watcher can't process it.

  If you get that exception you should try again a little while later.

EDIT: After looking at the code, my answer still makes sense.

Comment: Once upon a time, I had the exact same issue with using the FileSystemWatcher in one process and writing using another process.  Like you said, retrying to load the file a little while later is what I needed to do to resolve the error when I encountered it.